# Default value for description tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, parameters

I have a lot of static methods that require a SqlConnection as parameter. In the `<param>`-tag I always write "opened Connection to DB". As I am a programmer I am lazy. Is there any way to define a default description for a parameter? The name is always the same.
I haven't found any hint in the options of Visual Studio or in a google search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know there is **not** such an option. If i read your question you should better think about your code. In my point of view it is not a very good solution to pass an opened ado.net `DbConnection` to some static methods. But this is not the question.

What you could use is some Visual Studio snippets that you create on your own. May this help you out.

Comment: I think passing an opened `SqlConnection` is fine as all the methods are as small as possible to be reusable and I don't want to open let's say 5 connections for one task. I created a code snippet, thank you for the suggestion. It's not perfect but a lot closer to it than before.